# how to detect the end of outgoing ringtone?

Tags: android, uri, phone-call, ringtone

I want to make a call with my program and after that recognize the call status . I want to detect the end of outgoing ringtone.

How to detect the end of outgoing ringtone ?

I use of Flowing code for make call .

```
EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtcall);        
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", ed.getText().toString(), null);
callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,uri);
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code snippet can help you in finding the phone call current statue whether its picked, ringing or idle. You can easily use these states and implement your functionality accordingly.

```
 private class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
 {        
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
            {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

                //TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE
                //TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
                //TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING
            }
 }
```

Comment: please give me some more explanation

Comment: Just make the call and after that whenever you find call status is CALL_STATE_IDLE,  means its rejected or ringtone ended on other side.

Answer (score 0):

Check by This:- you will be able to call user

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+9189745847"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

and also use in androidmanifest.xml file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: thanks a lot .i want to detect the end of outgoing ringtone .how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at intent NEW_OUTGOING_CALL

```
 <receiver android:name=".receiver.OutgoingCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then you can check the state of call with a PhoneStateListener :

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

protected static final String CLASS_TAG = "OutgoingCallReceiver : ";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if(null == bundle) return;

    String phonenumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, CLASS_TAG + "phone number " + phonenumber);

        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, CLASS_TAG + "RINGING");
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, CLASS_TAG + "OFFHOOK");
                    Process.onCallStateIsOFFHOOK();
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    Process.onCallStateIsIDLE();
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, CLASS_TAG + "IDLE");
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, CLASS_TAG + "Default: " + state);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
}
```

In the Process class you can detect the ringtone and create more state like CALLBEGINS, CALLANSWERED by recording the VOICE_CALL. 
Example of onCallStateIsIDLE() :

```
public void onCallStateIsIDLE() {
    setSpeakingOn(false);
    if (stateCall == STATE_CALLANSWERED ||
            stateCall == STATE_CALLBEGINS ||
            stateCall == STATE_DIALISOFFHOOK ||
            stateCall == STATE_DIALENDREQUESTED) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, CLASS_TAG + " - forcing state : STATE_DIALREADY : old state = " + stateCall);
        stateCall = STATE_DIALREADY;
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain more about process class .